# Segmentation Fault For Struct When All Values Are Non-Null

Tags: c

```
char *s = sbrk(some_num); 
if (s != (char *)-1) {    
  some_struct = (SomeStruct *)s;
  some_struct->num = 8; //num is an int [*SEG FAULT OCCURS ON THIS LINE*]
}
```

Debugging using gdb:

```
p some_struct  => (SomeStruct *) 0xef7100
p some_struct->num  => 0
```

From a previous q/a, I understand that seg faults occur when something is NULL, but in this example,  some_struct, some_struct->num, and 8 are all **non-NULL**.

**Why does the segmentation fault occur? How can I set some_struct->num to some int value?**

Comment: Seg fault is NOT only when pointer is NULL, it is when you have wrong access to memory.

Comment: Please post a minimal amount of code that can be verified in practice.

Comment: either 0xef7100 isn't a valid pointer, or num is a *int not an int

Comment: Updated the question, to provide more details

Comment: Wrong access to memory / not a valid pointer --- thanks, I'll try to look into this

Comment: @GangstaGraham where did you get the idea of using `sbrk`?  It's an old and almost deprecated API for memory allocation.  We have been using `malloc` for decades (perhaps except on some embedded systems?)

Comment: i'm trying to do my own version of malloc, using sbrk

Answer (score 1):

The pointer some_struct needs to point to some valid memory. If the function some_function returns the pointer to some local volatile variable that variable will be lost when some_function exits.

To avoid segfault you could declare the local variable in some_function as static, or you could allocate the memory from heap by letting some_function call malloc. If some_function allocates the memory with malloc it will be the responsibility of the caller to make sure that the memory is later freed.

Another way to avoid segfault would be to not return the pointer to a local variable but a global variable. However, most people agree that global variables should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful! Due to the request of commenters, I have now added more details: some_function --> sbrk(some_num)

Comment: If you do not allocate enough memory for your entire struct you might get segfault when writing to a part of the struct which is outside of the allocated memory.

Comment: Also, using malloc instead of sbrk to allocate memory is considered more portable.

Answer (score 0):

It's worthwhile to become familiar with the concept of virtual memory which underlies most of modern OS's today.

Under an OS with virtual memory, every memory address (actually virtual address) is similar to telephone number in that you cannot call someone at every combination of some 10 digits.

You are supopsed to call at only those numbers listed in the telephone book.

Otherwise you'll hear "Sorry, this number is currently out of service".

Likewise, only those virtual addresses listed in the "page table" of each process (always automatically and transparently maintained by OS) are valid for the process to access.

SEGV is OS's way of saying "Sorry, this virtual address is currently out of service."

`malloc` (and `sbrk`) can basically ask OS to allocate a memory chunk of the specified size for you and to register its address to the page table.